# react cant read the image json url content

Tags: reactjs, json

I have local json data's and I'm going to map through them
as a problem react cant read image url while mapping it
but when I import the images as something like logo or etc... it shows the image

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your code as text instead of an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

use require to import pictures

```
<img src={require(cat.img)}/>
```

Comment: But there is no require in tutorials

Answer (score 0):

you can map images without importing
you just have to put images in public folder